# how to remove advertisement in opencart admin panel

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

How to remove opencart Advertisement in admin panel.

Here you see the Adverisement:

[image: Advertisement that I want to remove]

Comment: It is on  default installation? Maybe you have installed additional sage Pay module, which has this advertisement.

Comment: The twig file for this page will be somewhere in /admin/view/template/ but if you can't find that just use adblock.

Comment: "It is on default installation?" Yes it is in 3.0.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your OpenCart installation go to file

`/admin/controller/extension/extension/promotion.php`

and add replace this code on `line 18`

```php
return $response;
```

with this

```php
return '';
```

This will remove any promotion you see in your OpenCart admin panel.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Dmitriy Zhuk's answer is the easiest to apply.
An alternative if you want the change as a mod is to use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Hide promotions in admin panel</name>
    <code>skippromotion</code>
    <version>3.0x</version>
    <author>TH</author>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702884</link>
    <file path="admin/controller/extension/extension/*.php">
    <!-- Remove the 'promotions' feature -->
        <operation error="log">
            <search><![CDATA[$data['promotion'] = $this->load->controller('extension/extension/promotion');]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
$data['promotion'] = '';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Save it as 'install.xml', zip it up as 'skippromotion.ocmod.zip' and upload it using the 'Installer' in the admin panel - then go to 'Modifications', enable the mod and refresh your mod cache. The ads should disappear from the admin panel.

Note that this mod works in a different way to Dmitriy Zhuk's answer, it's replacing every call to admin/controller/extension/extension/promotion.php rather than the value that script returns.

Obviously you'll need to disable the mod and change OPENCART_SERVER in your config if you ever start your own farm of OpenCart installations and want to advertise to your users.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps better yet if your're going the edit route like I did:

```
 <?php
class ControllerExtensionExtensionPromotion extends Controller {
    public function index() {
    // MOD Eliminate Admin promotions - just return nothing.
    // we don't need to curl anything and might make site a touch faster
    return '';
    }
}
```